# Viewing a paraboloid from a point outside it

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, 3d, quadrics

Suppose you're given the paraboloid

$ z = a x^2 + b y^2 + c $

which you're viewing from the point $A$ that lies outside.  What will be the equation of the cone of view of the paraboloid from $A$?

**My approach:**

The matrix-vector form of the paraboloid is obtained by defining $ r= [x, y, z]^T $, and

$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} a && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && b && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $ and $q = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ - 1\end{bmatrix} $, then the equation is

$ r^T Q r + q^T r + c = 0 $

A ray originating at $A$ and having a direction vector $V$ is given parametrically by

$ r = A + t V $

Substitute this into the equation of the paraboloid

$ (A + t V)^T Q (A + t V) + q^T (A + t V) + c = 0 $

expand

$ t^2 (V^T Q V) + t ( 2 V^T Q A + q^T V) + A^T Q A + q^T A + c = 0 $

Since we want this ray to be tangential to the paraboloid, the two have to intersect in a signle point, which is only possible if the discriminant of the above quadratic equation in $t$ is zero.  Hence,

$ (2 V^T Q A + q^T V)^2 -  4(V^T Q V) (A^T Q A + q^T A + c ) = 0 $

which can be written as the following quadratic form

$ V^T \left( (2 Q A + q )(2 Q A + q)^T -  4(A^T Q A + q^T A + c) Q \right) V = 0 $

Since $V = \dfrac{1}{t} ( r - A ) $

Then the equation of the cone of view of the paraboloid is

$ (r - A)^T Q_c (r - A) = 0$

where

$ Q_c = (2 Q A + q )(2 Q A + q)^T -  4(A^T Q A + q^T A + c) Q $

I've implemented this and graphed it on [this SAGE page](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlUdFuhCAQfL_Ef9g3FYECAnoPfsml11hrrIl3GM8a9eu7GK-1aQhkh53dYYeZLnSlMBZTOUThvKMwDk59CQXMV_ViNSSwXBVskQEGa3CaBGanuhrdEF1SQcHillZwq8wrVk_ykGdpyoU2WqUqp8Cs5eIscm1Nhkgazc9CaCXtVqig-KnbmRSeDSiIjeSbC3zWJEnlHtEYJ5Mij_aOUXCq3L1GAjNcZLlUhuAUwBTXWmqB7yM4TLLiVkTyzOwcsjBFBD-nmQcr88kc44WsibHcUxIpFcebJFXSX6xMCuFTEJwaVGxvfddW7fjWd25MP6K-pBDNlGmB5uARI1xw5CNGu5na_POwcp0birBrm8_xvfuqQwquL7Hlgu0lhfLRozfFRVJc3okGkv-63oBf5R_hI9pl_6i6obw3B8mCm6dCXw7lrR6HtnpqTNhkxO-goEjfxp74DVg0lHo=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

It looks right.  The plot also features the tangency curve which is an ellipse shown in blue.

Your comments, or alternative solutions are highly appreciated.

Thank you all.